# configuring xdebug 2.6 with php 7.2 on osx

Tags: php, macos, xdebug

I'm trying to install xdebug but after a lot of effort still can't, I've tried this https://medium.com/@roberto.b/how-to-install-xdebug-with-my-php-7-on-my-macosx-f85dbac91e59 and a lot of stackoverflow question and still nothing,

I'm doing something wrong but can't figure out whats, any help on this please...
 This is what i get on my error.log

```
[Sat Apr 07 19:21:35.785293 2018] [so:warn] [pid 28523] AH01574: module php7_module is already loaded, skipping
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so:  dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so, 9): Symbol not found: _zend_pass_function
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so
Failed loading /usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/opcache.so:  dlopen(/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/opcache.so, 9): Symbol not found: _zend_empty_string
  Referenced from: /usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/opcache.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/opcache.so
[Sat Apr 07 19:21:35.904894 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28523] AH00163: Apache/2.4.28 (Unix) PHP/7.0.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Apr 07 19:21:35.905015 2018] [core:notice] [pid 28523] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

hope you can help guys!
Regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to have it working with instructions from the official Xdebug site.

It provides tailored installation instructions based on your current php setup, retrieved from phpinfo() or from php -i : https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

The instructions you will get are almost the same as the one described in the article you mentioned, but the versions are different. FYI, my setup is PHP 7.2, Xdebug 2.6.0 on Mac OS X.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks! you lead me to what's wrong with my install.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, if you have this error, you have to check your cli php version versus your browser or apache php version, that's where i have problems and after that it's easy to fix so regards for helping me.